# In sklearn elastic net how does the alpha and l1_ratio relate to lambda_1 and lambda_2

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the paper by Zou and Hastie http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/elasticnet.pdf the elastic net is defined with two regularization parameters λ1 and λ2 .They also provide another form with the use of an elastic net penalty term a where a constraint alpha is defined as  α = λ2 /λ1 + λ2.

My question is in the scikit-learn elastic net module whats is the relationship of the alpha and l1_ratio parameters to the parameters in the paper?

As far as I understood the l1_ratio in sklearn is equal to λ2 /λ1 + λ2.and alpha in sklearn is eqaul to λ1 + λ2.Is this correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: @Maxime although it may appear to be mathematical what I need to know is how the parameters we tune in the sklearn elastic net implementation translate into the theoretical model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is written in the [docstring of the ElasticNet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html) class:

The objective function minimized by `sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet` is:

```
1 / (2 * n_samples) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * l1_ratio * ||w||_1 + 0.5 * alpha * (1 - l1_ratio) * ||w||^2_2
```

So `lamba_1 == alpha * l1_ratio` and `lambda_2 == 0.5 * alpha * (1 - l1_ratio)`.

Comment: Thank you! this kind of cleared the doubts I had, although I think the 0.5 in lambda_2 can be disregarded for my purpose.